# Error while using pymysql in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pymysql

I am using pymysql client to connect to mysql in my flask API, 
everything works fine for some days(around 1-2 days) after that suddenly it starts to throw this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1039, in _write_bytes
    self._sock.sendall(data)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 194, in post
    result={'resultCode':100,'resultDescription':'SUCCESS','result':self.getStudentATData(studentId,args['chapterId'])}
  File "Main.py", line 176, in getStudentATData
    cur.execute("my query")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 855, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1092, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1044, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))")
```

And if restart the application it again works fine, i have tried everything but cant seem to get away with this, can anyone help?
As suggested, i am implemented a retry kind of mechanism but that didn't solve the problem

```
def connect(self):
        #db connect here
    def cursor(self):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return cursor
```

And consuming it like DB().cursor()

Comment: Connect to the database once in the code, not inside an exception clause.

Comment: isn't that what i did? Trying to get a cursor and if unable to get, then reconnecting

Comment: which server do you use to run your flask app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see, you have two options:

- Create new connection for every query, then close it. Like this:

  ```
  def db_execute(query):
       conn = MySQLdb.connect(*)
       cur = conn.cursor()
       cur.execute(query)
       res = cur.fetchall()
       cur.close()
       conn.close()
       return res
  ```
- Better way is to use Connection Pool like [SqlAlchemy.pool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html) with pool_pre_ping argument and custom connection function.

Comment: closing a connection helped, but i am worried about the performance, thats why not giving bounty yet.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, you need to decide whether you want to maintain a persistent connection to MySQL. The latter performs better, but need a little maintenance.

Default [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) in MySQL is 8 hours. Whenever a connection is idle longer than `wait_timeout` it's closed. When MySQL server is restarted, it also closes all established connections. Thus if you use a persistent connection, you need to check before using a connection if it's alive (and if not, reconnect). If you use per request connection, you don't need to maintain the state of connection, because connection are always fresh.

## Per request connection

A non-persistent database connection has evident overhead of opening connection, handshaking, and so on (for both database server and client) per each incoming HTTP request.

Here's a quote from Flask's official tutorial [regarding database connections](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/):

> Creating and closing database connections all the time is very inefficient, so you will need to keep it around for longer. Because database connections encapsulate a transaction, you will need to make sure that only one request at a time uses the connection. An elegant way to do this is by utilizing the application context.

Note, however, that *application context* is initialised per request (which is kind of veiled by efficiency concerns and Flask's lingo). And thus, it's still very inefficient. However it should solve your issue. Here's stripped snippet of what it suggests as applied to `pymysql`:

```
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, g, request    

app = Flask(__name__)    

def connect_db():
    return pymysql.connect(
        user = 'guest', password = '', database = 'sakila', 
        autocommit = True, charset = 'utf8mb4', 
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def get_db():
    '''Opens a new database connection per request.'''        
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = connect_db()
    return g.db    

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    '''Closes the database connection at the end of request.'''    
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()    

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    city = request.args.get('city')

    cursor = get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city = %s', city)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row:
      return 'City "{}" is #{:d}'.format(city, row['city_id'])
    else:
      return 'City "{}" not found'.format(city)
```

## Persistent connection

For a persistent connection database connection there are two major options. Either you have a pool of connections or map connections to worker processes. Because normally Flask WSGI applications are served by threaded servers with fixed number of threads (e.g. uWSGI), thread-mapping is easier and as efficient.

There's a package, [DBUtils](https://cito.github.io/DBUtils/UsersGuide.html#functionality), which implements both, and [`PersistentDB`](https://cito.github.io/DBUtils/UsersGuide.html#id1) for thread-mapped connections.

One important caveat in maintaining a persistent connection is transactions. The API for reconnection is [`ping`](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html#pymysql.connections.Connection.ping). It's safe for auto-committing single-statements, but it can be disrupting in between a transaction (a little more details [here](https://mysqlsimplequerybuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/design.html#persistent-connection)). DBUtils takes care of this, and should only reconnect on `dbapi.OperationalError` and `dbapi.InternalError` (by default, controlled by `failures` to initialiser of `PersistentDB`) raised outside of a transaction.

Here's how the above snippet will look like with `PersistentDB`.

```
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, g, request
from DBUtils.PersistentDB import PersistentDB    

app = Flask(__name__)    

def connect_db():
    return PersistentDB(
        creator = pymysql, # the rest keyword arguments belong to pymysql
        user = 'guest', password = '', database = 'sakila', 
        autocommit = True, charset = 'utf8mb4', 
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def get_db():
    '''Opens a new database connection per app.'''

    if not hasattr(app, 'db'):
        app.db = connect_db()
    return app.db.connection()    

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    city = request.args.get('city')

    cursor = get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city = %s', city)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row:
      return 'City "{}" is #{:d}'.format(city, row['city_id'])
    else:
      return 'City "{}" not found'.format(city)
```

## Micro-benchmark

To give a little clue what performance implications are in numbers, here's micro-benchmark.

I ran:

- `uwsgi --http :5000 --wsgi-file app_persistent.py --callable app --master --processes 1 --threads 16`
- `uwsgi --http :5000 --wsgi-file app_per_req.py --callable app --master --processes 1 --threads 16`

And load-tested them with concurrency 1, 4, 8, 16 via:

```
siege -b -t 15s -c 16 http://localhost:5000/?city=london
```

[image: chart]

Observations (for my local configuration):

1. A persistent connection is ~30% faster,
2. On concurrency 4 and higher, uWSGI worker process peaks at over 100% of CPU utilisation (`pymysql` has to parse MySQL protocol in pure Python, which is the bottleneck),
3. On concurrency 16, `mysqld`'s CPU utilisation is ~55% for per-request and ~45% for persistent connection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is an issue with Flask/pymysql as much as it is a symptom of your MySQL timeout configurations. I assume this is some sort of cloud database instance?

Have a look at this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/how-long-is-too-long-for-mysql-connections-to-sleep

And I'd post your question there with specifics about your setup and you may be able to get a configuration answer.

A Python solution would be to use something like sqlalchemy & flask-sqlalchemy then set the configuration variable `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 3600` to recycle connections after an hour (or whatever value you desire). Alternatively if you don't want to add that much bulk to your project you could implement a connection "timer" feature to recycle the connection yourself in the background:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyConnectionPool(object)
    """Class that returns a database connection <= 1 hour old"""
    refresh_time = timedelta(hours=1)

    def __init__(self, host, user, pass):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.pass = pass

        self.db = self._get_connection()

    @property
    def connection(self):

        if self.refresh <= datetime.now():
            self.db = self._get_connection()

        return self.db

    def _get_connection(self):
        self.refresh = datetime.now() + self.refresh_time
        return pymysql.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.user,
            passwd=self.pass
        )
```

Comment: This didn't work, i am still facing issues. i will edit the question with modified code

Comment: this seems to work `conn.query('set  wait_timeout=60 * 60 * 24')`  on the connection object to change the connection timeout.  Your refresh_time would need to be lower than 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a dB ping , and if that fails reconnecting before each call?
The other thing I found with flask was if I didn’t close the connection after each call I would end up with situations like this.

Sorry for lack of detail but I’m typing this on a phone and scrolling through all your code was had work :-)

```
class MyDatabase():
    def __init__(self, host, user, passwd, db, charset):
        self.host = host
        self.usr = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.db = db
        self.curclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        self.charset = charset
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.usr, passwd=self.passwd, db=self.db,
                                      cursorclass=self.curclass, charset=self.charset)


    def get_keywords(self):
        self.connection.connect()
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        sql = """
    SELECT * FROM input_keywords
    """
        rows = None
        try:
            cur.execute(sql)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.connection.rollback()
        finally:
            cur.close()
            self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.close()
        return rows
```

This then lets Flask create a connection for each request, and close it at the end.

So any method I call uses this pattern. This also allows for multiple requests etc (websites do that)

I'm not saying its perfect, but for every request to the db, you are creating, and closing the db connection so it should never time out.

This is very basic, and again, you could combine it with the ping() and allow this to create a new connection etc

Comment: Can you check the edit please? That is what i tried, i tried to reconnect and get a cursor is an error

Comment: And do you mean to close the connection or the cursor?

Comment: It sounds like you are opening a connection, keeping it open, and its timeing out and MySQL is then stopping you from connecting. I'll update my answer with system I use with Flask